# Look back column based on date and rank in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I am trying to create a new column based on rank, changing every month. Below is the sample input data.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4),
             rank=c(3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3),
             dates=c('2019-06-15','2019-07-15','2019-08-15','2019-09-15','2019-10-15','2019-11-15','2019-12-15',
                     '2019-10-15','2019-11-15','2019-12-15',
                     '2019-11-15','2019-12-15','2019-12-15'))
```

This is expected output and I want rows from the latest date.

```
 id   rank   dates      new_col
  1    2    2019-12-15       0
  2    1    2019-12-15       0
  3    2    2019-12-15       1
  4    3    2019-12-15       0
```

`new_col` will indicate an increase in the `rank` from a 6-month look-back? 
 For example, If a row is from December as `2` but they were `1` on the October row, then 
 in the December row we can put `new_col`= 1.

We have to restrict look back date to just **6 Months**.

Comment: What do you mean increase from a 6 month lookback? What if it's lower than last month but higher than 2 months ago, or vice versa? Or are you saying look back exactly six months, and for that date there will always be only a single row to compare with?

Comment: 6 Months look back means, checking for just 6 months in the dates and ignoring dates if greater than 6 months.

Comment: if its lower than last month,  but higher than 2 months ago. e.g 1,3,2 (rank) then it should be 0

Comment: And, 6 months look back means, checking ranks for just 6 months. e.g 1,1,1,1,1,2 (rank) then new_col should be 1

Comment: Another example would be 3,1,1,1,1,1,1 (rank) then new_col would be 0, because rank was 1 for the last 6 months

Comment: In general, you're looking at a sliding window operation, which to me suggests the `zoo` package. However, since you're looking for "6 months" and not "6 rows", then either you need a custom rolling function (possibly with the help of `zoo`, but not directly) or you need to *guarantee* that all dates for each `id` are contiguous (and then use `zoo`'s normal window by-row, not by-date).

Comment: (Which, btw, strikes out `dplyr` and `data.table` in the direct sense, though window operations will work once placed within either's environment.)

Comment: FYI, your data is a little helpful (for structure) but really under-useful here. A good set of sample data would include conditions that *do not match* your window. Having everything span 3 months when your window is 6 months will not help you test the validity of any code.

Comment: @r2evans I will add new sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using non-equi join in `data.table`:

```
#convert into IDate and get dates from 6m ago
DT[, dates := as.IDate(dates, format="%Y-%m-%d")][, c("start", "end") := 
    .(as.IDate(sapply(dates, function(x) seq(x, by="-6 months", length.out=2L)[2L])), dates)]

#extract latest rows for each id
latest <- DT[DT[, .I[.N], id]$V1]

#non-equi join and for each latest date of each id, check if the current rank is the highest over last 6m
DT[latest, on=.(id, dates>=start, dates<end), 
    by=.EACHI, {
        a <- +all(i.rank > x.rank)
        .(new_col=replace(a, is.na(a), 0L))
        }]
```

output:

```
   id      dates      dates new_col
1:  1 2019-06-15 2019-12-15       0
2:  2 2019-06-15 2019-12-15       0
3:  3 2019-06-15 2019-12-15       1
4:  4 2019-06-15 2019-12-15       0
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4),
    rank=c(3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3),
    dates=c('2019-06-15','2019-07-15','2019-08-15','2019-09-15','2019-10-15','2019-11-15','2019-12-15',
        '2019-10-15','2019-11-15','2019-12-15',
        '2019-11-15','2019-12-15','2019-12-15'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are willing to use data.table. First sort you data after the time variable. Use shift to get the last 2 values available (6 in your case), and take the max. Need to make sure that for each ID you have the complete time series, otherwise, it will take the last values available, I think. By comparing rank with rank_max you can determine whether the rank changed.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3) %>% as.character,
             rank=c(1,3,2,2,3,1,1,2,3),
             time=rep(1:3,3))
setorder(df, time)
df[, rank_max := do.call(pmax, shift(rank, 1:2, type = "lag")), by=id]

   id rank time rank_max
1:  1    1    1       NA
2:  2    2    1       NA
3:  3    1    1       NA
4:  1    3    2       NA
5:  2    3    2       NA
6:  3    2    2       NA
7:  1    2    3        3
8:  2    1    3        3
9:  3    3    3        2
```

Comment: you can change the pmax within the do.call statement to choose whether you want to select the max or the min.

Comment: now that I read all the new comments I am not sure this is useful anymore. In particular this is a bit unclear: "if its lower than last month, but higher than 2 months ago. e.g 1,3,2 (rank) then it should be 0". If past changes offset each other, then using averages could maybe be useful: df[, mean := mean( shift(rank, 1:2, type = "lag") %>% unlist), by=id]